Open Educational Resources Listed on CV
I have been contributing to OER Commons, and was wondering how I could consider adding that to my CV. I have two works now that I used LaTex to construct problems, and develop flashcards for individuals learning certain topics. In what constructive area would that go under Volunteering, or would I put that under experience, as well as with the links to the material I have made on the website? My goal is to leverage that into applying for an adjunct faculty role, or even an educator position.

Do you have a PhD?

@AzorAhai-him- I am going for my Master's at the moment. I graduate in about 3 semesters because I am going part-time.

Most CVs are designed by the person themself. With the exception of a few "necessary" sections, you can do pretty much what you like. A section labeled "Other" or "Contributions" should be fine. Even "Open Educational Resources" would be appropriate.

+1 Right but how would I go leveraging these contributions to a point where I apply these OER material to a instructor based position, or would it be not worthwhile?

They are what they are. Their value will be judged by others. Be prepared to speak of your contributions in any interviews, especially if you expect to continue with them.
